# Dynamic content for additional column with copy activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to create a simple copy activity to copy data from a source Azure Table to a sink Mongo Cosmos DB but want to also output an extra column to the sink data where the content of the additional column is the run id (or something else that is dynamically set per run).

I can add the extra column easily by defining an additional column in the source schema but can't work out how to set the content (presumably it should be set in the activity), hence the value for the added field is always NULL in the output DB

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same, or something similar, and create a Dynamic select statement in your copy activity.  So something like SELECT @{item().sourceTableCustomColumnList}, @pipeline().RunId FROM @{item().sourceTableName}

You may refer the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/09ff6f2d-7e33-4891-a601-234d5970bd16/adding-additional-column-in-data-being-saved-in-cosmosdb-by-azure-data-factorys-copy-activity?forum=AzureDataFactory) thread which addressing similar issue.

Hope this helps.